# Closed-form solution of $y''(x) - y(x) \ln(x) = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, closed-form

Is there any closed-form expression for the solution of
$$
y''(x) - y(x) \ln(x) = 0
$$
in terms of special functions / integrals / infinite sums or other?

Comment: Probably not: Maple does not find any.